# Explanation for: "function" == typeof code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am working on someone script and I don't understand following line. Can someone explain me this line?

```
 var self = this,
 "function" == typeof self.options.callback && self.options.callback.call(self)
 callback: function() { .. }
```

**options is object**

Comment: Look like a conditional statement but used as an expression!

Comment: Thankx for quick replay, but how that function call when i remove this line from script I am getting error. There is callback function but I am not sure how that function call here? Can you explain me this?

Comment: @hindmost: No, it really doesn't.

Comment: For the odd code, see the marked duplicate. If you don't understand what the `("function" == typeof self.options.callback)` part means, check the [MDN docs on the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: when I console "self.options.callback" this line i am getting callback function, but when i console "self.options.callback.call(self)" this line i am getting undefined. Addition if I remove "self.options.callback.call(self)" this my script doesn't work...

Comment: @Bergi i am not asking about && operator

Comment: @simpleclick: Uh, [`.call(self)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) just calls that function and returns the result? What else is it that you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

It is verifying that the type of `self.options.callback` is a function and that `self.options.callback.call(self)` is resolved to `true`.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

Comment: `typeof` can't span the `&&`

Comment: yes, I realize after reading the inquiry code more closely.

Comment: cool, just noticed update

Comment: so it will check "self.options.callback" is function, if it is function than it will return true? is that what you mean?

Comment: @simpleclick exactly, and of course the conditional statement continues to check if `self.options.callback.call(self)` returns true.